# Android APK file download stuck on 0.00B/0.00B

Tags: android, deployment, apk

I'm trying to download an apk file that I've signed and exported using the Android wizard in Eclipse in the release mode. I've hosted it on IIS with and set the MIME types as `.apk` and `application/vnd.android.package-archive`. I try to open this file on a test Android tablet that I have with me and the download is stuck on 0.00B / 0.00B with filename as `<Unknown>` and options to pause or cancel downloads.

It's not giving me any errors, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Has anyone encountered a similar situation before?

Thanks, 
Teja.

Comment: Does it work if you download it in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out having a self signed (untrusted) certificate for the server you've hosted your app at can cause the problem. Changing servers to one that has the right certificate let me download the app fine.

I'm sure there's a browser setting somewhere that lets you download files from untrusted servers, if anyone can point that out, I'd gladly mark that as the answer.